# JSON-LD for multiple pages (Course Intro page & Lesson pages) that make up a course

Tags: seo, schema.org, json-ld, structured-data

I'm unsure how to mark-up my pages that make up a course. Let's say I have the following pages, where the first in each group is a Course Introduction page, and each of the following is a single Lesson Page within the course. All the pages together technically make up the entire course. The course is completely online, and you go at your own pace.

```
www.myeducationalsite.com/course-1
www.myeducationalsite.com/course-1/lesson-1
www.myeducationalsite.com/course-1/lesson-2
www.myeducationalsite.com/course-1/lesson-3

www.myeducationalsite.com/course-2
www.myeducationalsite.com/course-2/lesson-1
www.myeducationalsite.com/course-2/lesson-2
```

I am using the `Course` object from schema.org to describe the Course Introduction page, but I was unsure which object type to use for the Lesson pages.

I'm also unsure how to describe their relationships. The `hasCourseInstance` property didn't seem to be what I need, but maybe I'm misunderstanding. I understand I can use `hasPart` and `isPartOf` to describe relationships, but I was unsure what @type to even use on the Lesson pages.

How can I use JSON-LD to describe the relationship of the pages that make up the Course?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsing the schema.org site tells that the [hasPart](https://schema.org/hasPart) relationship points to a [CreativeWork](https://schema.org/CreativeWork), the most relevant sub-class of which for your use-case might perhaps be [LearningResource](https://schema.org/LearningResource):

> The LearningResource type can be used to indicate [CreativeWorks](https://schema.org/CreativeWork)
> (whether physical or digital) that have a particular and explicit
> orientation towards learning, education, skill acquisition, and other
> educational purposes.

So perhaps something along these lines?

```
[
  {
    "@context": "https://schema.org/",
    "@id": "https://www.myeducationalsite.com/course-1",
    "@type": "Course",
    "hasPart": [
      {
        "@type": "LearningResource",
        "@id": "https://www.myeducationalsite.com/course-1/lesson-1"
      },
      {
        "@type": "LearningResource",
        "@id": "https://www.myeducationalsite.com/course-1/lesson-2"
      },
      {
        "@type": "LearningResource",
        "@id": "https://www.myeducationalsite.com/course-1/lesson-3"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "@context": "https://schema.org/",
    "@id": "https://www.myeducationalsite.com/course-2",
    "@type": "Course",
    "hasPart": [
      {
        "@type": "LearningResource",
        "@id": "https://www.myeducationalsite.com/course-2/lesson-1"
      },
      {
        "@type": "LearningResource",
        "@id": "https://www.myeducationalsite.com/course-2/lesson-2"
      }
     ]
  }
]
```

[Here](https://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-nquads&json-ld=%5B%7B%22%40context%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2F%22%2C%22%40id%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.myeducationalsite.com%2Fcourse-1%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22Course%22%2C%22hasPart%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22LearningResource%22%2C%22%40id%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.myeducationalsite.com%2Fcourse-1%2Flesson-1%22%7D%2C%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22LearningResource%22%2C%22%40id%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.myeducationalsite.com%2Fcourse-1%2Flesson-2%22%7D%2C%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22LearningResource%22%2C%22%40id%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.myeducationalsite.com%2Fcourse-1%2Flesson-3%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40context%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2F%22%2C%22%40id%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.myeducationalsite.com%2Fcourse-2%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22Course%22%2C%22hasPart%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22LearningResource%22%2C%22%40id%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.myeducationalsite.com%2Fcourse-2%2Flesson-1%22%7D%2C%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22LearningResource%22%2C%22%40id%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.myeducationalsite.com%2Fcourse-2%2Flesson-2%22%7D%5D%7D%5D&frame=%7B%7D&context=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22name%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Fname%22%2C%22description%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Fdescription%22%2C%22image%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Fimage%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22%40id%22%7D%2C%22geo%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Fgeo%22%2C%22latitude%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Flatitude%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22xsd%3Afloat%22%7D%2C%22longitude%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Flongitude%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22xsd%3Afloat%22%7D%2C%22xsd%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23%22%7D%7D) is a link to JSON-LD Playground for the above.